# Deserialize a Java object which I get from a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, serialization

JSP code:

```
<%
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);
output.writeObject(new BigDecimal("111"));
output.flush();
output.close();

response.getOutputStream().write(stream.toByteArray());

out.clear();
out = pageContext.pushBody();
%>
```

code at client, (response is a object of `org.apache.http.HttpResponse`)

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
is.read(buff);

ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(buff);

ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
```

I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C68746D
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:783)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:280)
```

Comment: are you using over http or some other protocol

Comment: Any reason to use JSP instead of a simpler servlet?

Comment: When I use servlet, that's all okay ! thank you, but why ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
 HttpURLConnection uc   = null;
try
{
 URL url = new URL("http://12.13.152.12:7077/client.jsp");
 uc= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
 uc.setUseCaches (false);
 uc.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
 uc.setDoInput(true);
 uc.setDoOutput(true);
 uc.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type","application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8");
 uc.connect();
 oos = new ObjectOutputStream(uc.getOutputStream());
 oos.writeObject(new String("hello"));
}
catch(Exception ee)
{
}
finally
{
  oos.flush();
  oos.close();
  oos = null;
  uc.disconnect();
}
    **in client side**
*client.jsp*
InputStream inputStream = null;
ObjectInputStream ois = null;
try
{
    inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    String companyName`enter code here`="";
    String temp = (String)ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("temp ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be somewhere else the data is being written directly to output stream as bytes. The response stream has mix of object stream and bytes . Which fails during decoding because you are treating the entire content as objectstream.

Answer (score 0):

```
// JAVA code uses Apache HttpClient
public void testObjectStream() {
        try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8084/test_serialize.jsp");
                httpPost.setEntity(new SerializableEntity(new String("testing 123"), false));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(content);
                        System.out.println("obj : " + (String)ois.readObject());

                } else {
                        System.out.println("failed : " + statusCode);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
}

// JSP page (DO NOT ADD LINE BREAKS or the JSP will take control of the outputstream before you can)
// test_serialize.jsp - This JSP will read an object from the inputstream (a String in our test) and write it back to the outputstream

<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.io.*" %><%
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    String temp = (String)ois.readObject();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(new String(temp));
%>
```